# How to parse formatted email address into display name and email address?

Tags: c#, parsing, mailaddress

Given the email address: "Jim" <jim@example.com>

If I try to pass this to MailAddress I get the exception:

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

How do I parse this address into a display name (Jim) and email address (jim@example.com) in C#?

EDIT:  I'm looking for C# code to parse it.

EDIT2:  I found that the exception was being thrown by MailAddress because I had a space at the start of the email address string.

Comment: May I suggest MimeKit? It's a very standards-compliant library capable of parsing email addresses correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Parse String in format "Name <Email>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442635/how-to-parse-string-in-format-name-email)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are looking to parse the email address manually, you want to read RFC2822 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html#section-3.4).  Section 3.4 talks about the address format.

But parsing email addresses correctly is not easy and `MailAddress` should be able to handle most scenarios.

According to the MSDN documentation for `MailAddress`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8.aspx

It should be able to parse an address with a display name.  They give `"Tom Smith <tsmith@contoso.com>"` as an example.  Maybe the quotes are the issue?  If so, just strip the quotes out and use MailAddress to parse the rest.

```
string emailAddress = "\"Jim\" <jim@example.com>";

MailAddress address = new MailAddress(emailAddress.Replace("\"", ""));
```

Manually parsing RFC2822 isn't worth the trouble if you can avoid it.

Comment: Cool - I never know you could just send in 'Name <email@domain.com>'! I was just about to write another string splitting function :)

Comment: Maybe it helps someone, i had to use it with this slight difference because it wouldn't accept an empty char, because every possible value
for a char type is one character long. `MailAddress address = new MailAddress(emailAddress.Replace("\"", ""));`

Answer (score 5):

Works for me:

```
string s = "\"Jim\" <jim@example.com>";
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress a = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(s);
Debug.WriteLine("DisplayName:  " +  a.DisplayName);
Debug.WriteLine("Address:  " + a.Address);
```

The MailAddress class has a private method that parses an email address.  Don't know how good it is, but I'd tend to use it rather than writing my own.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
"Jimbo <jim@example.com>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new MailAddress("jim@example.com", "Jimbo");
```

to parse out the string you gave:

```
string input = "\"Jimbo\" jim@example.com";
string[] pieces = input.Split(' ');
MailAddress ma = new MailAddress(pieces[1].Replace("<", string.Empty).Replace(">",string.Empty), pieces[0].Replace("\"", string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 0):

try: "Jim" <jim@example.com>
not sure if it'll work, but that's how I generally see it in e-mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
string inputEmailString = "\"Jimbo\" <jim@example.com>";
string[] strSet =  inputEmailString.Split('\"','<','>');   

MailAddress mAddress = new MailAddress(strSet[0], strSet[2]);
```

Comment: I know how to call MailAddress, I need code to parse the given address.

Answer (score 0):

if you make the assumption there is always a space between the 2, you could just use String.Split(' ') to split it on the spaces. That would give you an array with the parts split.

so maybe like this:

```
string str = "\"Jimbo\" jim@example.com"
string[] parts = str.Trim().Replace("\"","").Split(' ')
```

An issue with this to check for is that if the display name has a space in it, it will be split into 2 or more items in your array itself, but the email would always be last.

Edit - you might also need to edit out the brackets, just add replaces with those.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this up, it grabs the first well formed e-mail address out of a string. That way you don't have to assume where the e-mail address is in the string

Lots of room for improvement, but I need to leave for work :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string email = "\"Jimbo\" <jim@example.com>";
        Console.WriteLine(parseEmail(email));
    }

    private static string parseEmail(string inputString)
    {
        Regex r = 
            new Regex(@"^((?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\.\-\+_]?)*)[a-zA-Z0-9])+)\@((?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\.\-_]?){0,62})[a-zA-Z0-9])+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6})$");

        string[] tokens = inputString.Split(' ');

        foreach (string s in tokens)
        {
            string temp = s;
            temp = temp.TrimStart('<'); temp = temp.TrimEnd('>');

            if (r.Match(temp).Success)
                return temp;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Not an e-mail address");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit "rough and ready" but will work for the example you've given:

```
        string emailAddress, displayname;
        string unparsedText = "\"Jimbo\" <jim@example.com>";
        string[] emailParts = unparsedText.Split(new char[] { '<' });

        if (emailParts.Length == 2)
        {
            displayname = emailParts[0].Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\"' });
            emailAddress = emailParts[1].TrimEnd('>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle embedded spaces, split on the brackets, as follows:

```
string addrin = "\"Jim Smith\" <jim@example.com>";
char[] bracks = {'<','>'};
string[] pieces = addrin.Split(bracks);
pieces[0] = pieces[0]
  .Substring(0, pieces[0].Length - 1)
  .Replace("\"", string.Empty);
MailAddress ma = new MailAddress(pieces[1], pieces[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I have done.  It's a little quick and dirty, but seems to work.

```
string emailTo = "\"Jim\" <jim@example.com>";
string emailRegex = @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|""(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*"")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])";
string emailAddress = Regex.Match(emailTo.ToLower(), emailRegex).Value;
string displayName = null;

try
{
    displayName = emailTo.Substring(0, emailTo.ToLower().IndexOf(emailAddress) - 1);
}
catch 
{
    // No display name 
}

MailAddress addr = new MailAddress(emailAddress, displayName);
```

Comments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in this language, but I see two issues you might want to check:

1- You don't know exactly why it was rejected. On immediate possibility was that it has a blacklist for example.com.

2- The real solution you want is to probably implement a strict validator. Stack Overflow is probably a good place to develop this, because there are lots of people with practical experience.

Here are a couple things you need:

1. trim whitespace and obviously cruft.
2. parse into individual parts (display name, left-hand-side of address, right-hand side of address).
3. validate each of these with a data structure specific validator. For example, the right-hand side needs to be a valid FQDN (or unqualified hostname if you are on a liberal mail system).

That's the best long-term approach to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest my regex-based solution for decoding email address field values ("From", "To") and field value "Subject"

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1198601/Parsing-and-Decoding-Values-of-Some-Email-Message

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/), as [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient), then you can use the methods Parse and TryParse of MimeKit.MailboxAddress. Here's an example.

```
[Test]
public void Should_Parse_EmailAddress_With_Alias()
{
    //Arrange
    var expectedAlias = "Jim";
    var expectedAddress = "jim@example.com";
    string addressWithAlias = "\"Jim\" <jim@example.com>";

    //Act
    var mailboxAddressWithAlias = MimeKit.MailboxAddress.Parse(addressWithAlias);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedAddress, mailboxAddressWithAlias.Address);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedAlias, mailboxAddressWithAlias.Name);
}
```