# How To Parse String in format "Name <Email>"

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a method which receives a contact in one of the following formats:

1 - "email@domain.com"

2 - "Name <email@domain.com>" OR "Name<email@domain.com>" (Spaces can exist)

If it is in format (1) I do nothing. In case of (2) I need to parse the name and email.

I never know in which format I will get the emails. But it will be one of the two.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is actually already a .NET class called [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) that can do this for you quite simply.
**UPDATE: It can not only get the display name but also the email address, username, and host.**

First include `using System.Net.Mail` and then you can get the info with something like this:

```
MailAddress email = new MailAddress("Johnny <johnny@example.com>");
string displayName = email.DisplayName;
string address = email.Address;
string user = email.User;
string host = email.Host;
```

This will work with the two scenarios that you described so `"Name <email@domain.com>"` and `"Name<email@domain.com>"` both work and give you `Name`. I went on and created a test that can be found [here](http://ideone.com/5IHkG) that will give you the sample output of:

```
'email@domain.com' =
   DisplayName = ''
   Address = 'email@domain.com'
   User = 'email'
   Host = 'domain.com'
'Name<email@domain.com>' =
   DisplayName = 'Name'
   Address = 'email@domain.com'
   User = 'email'
   Host = 'domain.com'
'Name <email@domain.com>' =
   DisplayName = 'Name'
   Address = 'email@domain.com'
   User = 'email'
   Host = 'domain.com'
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted, but you might want to use the `Address` property in your demo to show that it can not only extract the `DisplayName` but also the email.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thanks. I went on and added it to show some more info.

Comment: Yes, well spotted. In fact, in the end, I was converting it to MailAddress but I didn't know that MailAddress would do this by itself. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

`MailAddress` is a great solution, but unfortunately `System.Net.Mail` has not yet been ported to .NET Core.

I find that the following Regex solution works for reasonably well-formed inputs:

```cs
var re = new Regex(@"""?((?<name>.*?)""?\s*<)?(?<email>[^>]*)");
var match = re.match(input);

var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
var email = match.Groups["email"].Value;
```

I have tested this with the following kinds of inputs:

```
bob@example.com
<bob@example.com>
Bob Example <bob@example.com>
Bob Example<bob@example.com>
"Bob Example" <bob@example.com>
"Example, Bob J." <bob@example.com>
```

Answer (score 1):

MimeKit [has a method](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MailboxAddress_Parse_7.htm) for that:

```cs
MailboxAddress addr = MailboxAddress.Parse("Mr. Curious <mrcurious@example.com>");
```

It works on .NET, Mono, and .NET Core as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's few ways to do that, but first one that occurred was

```
String[] parts = someValue.Trim().Split(new char[] {' '},false);

if (parts.Length > 1) then
{
// in format "Name OR Name" or more correctly not in format someone@domain.com
}
```

Comment: I corrected my code ... I cannot split by space because in (2) I can have or not a space between the contact and email.

Comment: Can you have a space in the first format?. If not the above will identify whether it's 1 or 2, which what you seem to be asking.

Comment: there are spaces around OR aren't there?

Comment: Yes, there might be spaces. Example: 1- "johnsmith@domain.com"; 2 - "John Smith<johnsmith@domain.com>" / "John Smith <johnsmith@domain.com>" ... There might be a space or more spaces between the name and email.

Comment: This is neither C# nor VB.NET, it won't compile anyway.

Comment: And where did the / some from? Is that OR now. How can we give you code to split up a string if you keep changing the characteristics of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either design a simple regular expression (which would, in my opinion, be the elegant solution in this case) or call `Split()` with `'<'` as the separator, `Trim()` the first string and remove the closing `'>'` from the second one.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do everything with a single Regex (@"\<(.*?)\>") but I am missing something ...

Answer (score 0):

You may use Regex:

```
        var str = "Name<email@domain.com>";

        var r = new Regex("(?<name>.*?)<(?<email>.*?)>");

        if(r.IsMatch(str))
        {
            var m = r.Match(str);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Trim());
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["email"]);
        }
```

Here I assume that you needn't validate email format and name doesn't have < or > characters

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex.

```
^((.*?)\s*?<)(.*?)>?$
```

The name (if available) would be in the second capturing group, and the email would be in the third.

Example:

```
var match = Regex.Match("Name <email@domain.com>", @"^((.*?)\s*?<)(.*?)>?$");
string name = math.Groups[2].Value;
string email = match.Groups[3].Value;
```